# WordPress add_image_size Not Generating Widths Between 1600px and 2300px

Tags: php, wordpress, image, image-processing

I am trying to generate images from 3840w on down, using whatever larger starting width image is uploaded.  The WordPress documentation is pretty straightforward, yet I have tried every combination and nothing works, including using a plugin.  I scoured the web and nobody seems to have had this type of problem of it skipping a few sizes even though I am trying it on the latest bare base WPEngine WordPress setup.

Basically, the code will not generate images between around 1600w and 2300w, which is an issue when I need 1920w (1080p) images.  I used the following code:

```
add_filter( 'big_image_size_threshold', function(){ return false; } );

// adds image size for full 1080p (1920x1200)
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpdocs_theme_setup' );
function wpdocs_theme_setup() {
    add_image_size( '4k', 3840, 0, false );
    add_image_size( 'test12', 2600, 0, false );
    add_image_size( 'test11', 2500, 0, false );
    add_image_size( 'test0', 2400, 0, false );
    add_image_size( 'test9', 2300, 0, false );
    add_image_size( 'test8', 2200, 0, false );
    add_image_size( 'test7', 2100, 0, false );
    add_image_size( 'test6', 2000, 0, false );
    add_image_size( 'test5', 1900, 0, false );
    add_image_size( 'test4', 1800, 0, false );
    add_image_size( 'test3', 1700, 0, false );
    add_image_size( 'test2', 1600, 0, false );
    add_image_size( 'test1', 1500, 0, false );
    add_image_size( 'test', 123, 123 );
}
```

I changed out the themes, that did not work.  I tried this on a full setup and on a virgin setup with no plugins, nothing made it work.  I made the height 0 (for infinite) in the code above, but it also produced the same result when the number matched the width.

The images WordPress DOES generate are the following - by increasing size:

- 123x88  my add
- 150x150  WP standard
- 300x215  "
- 768x549  "
- 1024x732 "
- 1200x858 "
- 1500x1073  my add
- 1536x1099  WP standard
- 2400x1717  my add
- 2500x1788  "
- 2600x1860  "
- 3840x2747  my add

the original is a 7k jpg

So, as you can see it does not generate between 1536 and 2400.  The version of WordPress is 5.5.3, with PHP v7.4

I was hoping someone had come across this issue specifically or might have some insight into the workings of WP.

Comment: Hello @robfi can you look at the last paragraph from here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/#other-notes Maybe this is what they mean with "unexpected" behaviour. Can you check if those sizes are generated if you give them a fixed height?

Comment: Hi Hoargarth -- So I just tried a few options from that page, changing 0 to 9999, removing 'false' argument, setting height to match the width, adding a line a commented had made in that post "add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); " and alas, none of it worked.  I remove the image in media, verify in SFTP, recache, replace the image, to make sure no residual code is causing an issue.